# C# POCO to JS Object dynamically

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, signalr

I am looking at MVVM with Knockout.js. One of the things I would like to achieve is to "easily" get my code behind MVVM POCO to the client as a corresponding JS object.

The idea being that:

a) If I change the C# POCO it will also reflect in the JS Object
b) Changing a value in the POCO will result in the necessary interaction with the client to update the JS object

I am guessing this is when you would use SignalR (http://signalr.net/) to do this? And then use the mapping plugin from KO (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to turn this into observables.

So my questions are:

1. Are my assumptions correct in terms of getting the POCO server
   side data to KO via SignalR
2. Is there another way to achieve 1.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SignalR to push real-time changes to the POCO representation of your object to the client. I mean, it won't be automatic in terms of you change a property, it magically sends a message. You would have to build some plumbing to ensure you send a specific SignalR message when a particular object changed. You could choose to resend the entire representation of that object again (e.g. all current values) or you could send only the values that you know were changed for more efficiency.

From there you would need to update the corresponding JS representation of the object which, if you're using Knockout, would result in the proper notifications to all observers of said object. You could also do this in the other direction by observing a change on the JS object and sending a message back to the server.

Obviously the key will be that each object must have some kind of unique identity so that you can correlate the messages to/from the proper JS/POCO objects.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now to find out if someone has done the magic plumbing to send the messages backwards and forwards before I go and re-implement the wheel.